# Netziv's Ha'emek She'eila online?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet

Is Netziv's Ha'emek She'eila available online somewhere?

Comment: Your second question belongs on http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/ actually.

Comment: The length standard is there for a reason; feel free to bring it up on [meta] if you wish; but don't try to get around it by putting in unrelated material. Ways you could have improved this question and increased its length in one fell swoop are linking to a biography of the _N'tziv_ or a description of the _sefer_ or indicating where you already had checked for the _sefer_ (so that people not duplicate your work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Ha'emek She'elah is on Hebrewbooks.org, though they aren't labelled as such (you have to search for 'Sheiltos')

Links:

[Vol 1 on Beraishis-Shemos](http://hebrewbooks.org/39101)

[Vol 2 on Vayikra](http://hebrewbooks.org/39103)

[Vol 3 on Bamidbar-Devarim](http://hebrewbooks.org/39102)

Comment: I didn't think to search for the wrong spelling of a partial name of the work without mentioning the author!

Comment: @TzGaBeR It's not a wrong spelling. העמק שאלה is the Netziv's commentary on the [שאילתות דרב אחאי גאון](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achai_Gaon#A.E1.B8.A5a.27s_Sheiltot), and it frequently included in editions of the שאילתות.